# stop playing sound push notification

Tags: ios, push, playback, audio

Tried to find this already but can't find any questions which are asking quite the same thing.

Basically I have set up my push notifications, everything works fine and they are received both when the app is open and closed.

I recieve push, sound begins play. For some reason i need to cancel sound without active app.
Skype have this feature. When app is suspended, incoming call start to play sound by push. After  call cancelation sound stops.

UPD:
Is there a way to cancel the sound like Skype?
When Skype app is suspended iPhone receives PUSH for incoming call. Sound begins playing. When call cancel at other side iPhone stops play sound by second push. Anyone knows how this feature works?

Comment: probably with two notifications. first one with a sound second one with an empty sound. when the second one comes it will "play" the empty sound.

Comment: Could be @alinoz - the notification also changes text from "incoming" to "missed", but there is only one notification showed when looking under "All notifications" - got any insights on how that might be done?

Comment: hmm I think you can achieve something like that: The first notification is a alert + sound (with a real sound) and the second notification is only a sound notification with an silent sound (in this way the second notification will not be visible to the user but it will just cancel the sound of the first notification). I have not test this but I have no access to my mac next 2 weeks.

Comment: @user1072975 Have you managed to resolve this? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

You specify a bitmask of notification types when you register for notifications. If you don't want a sound to be played when notifications come in, remove UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound from that bitmask

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge)];
```

Comment: App is suspended. I think it will not help.

Answer (score 0):

I think they're using invisible push to trigger a local notification. Local notification may be cancelled, so they then cancel it when needed.